# Junit assert OR condition in my test case

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, junit3

In my test case, I get an integer value:

```
int val = getXXX();
```

Then, I would like to check if `val` either equals to 3 or equals to 5 which is OK in either case. So, I did:

```
assertTrue(val == 3 || val==5);
```

I run my test, the log shows `val` is 5, but my above assertion code failed with **AssertionFailedError**. Seems I can not use `assertTrue(...)` in this way, then, how to check true for OR condition?

Comment: Debug your test and inspect the value of `val` right before that `assertTrue` statement. Is it still 5?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

ive tried to write quick test:

```
@Test
public void testName() {
    int i = 5;
    junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(i == 3 || i == 5);

}
```

its passing always so i guess there is some inbetween code when your value is changed. 
You can use

```
org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(5, i);
```

to check value - this assertion will print out nice info whats wrong, for example:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :4
Actual   :5
```

Answer (score 59):

You can use [Hamcrest matchers](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) to get a clearer error message here:

```
int i = 2;
assertThat(i, Matchers.either(Matchers.is(3)).or(Matchers.is(5))

or

int i = 2;
assertThat(i, Matchers.anyOf(Matchers.is(3),Matchers.is(5)));
```

This will more clearly explain:

```
Expected: (is <3> or is <5>)
     but: was <2>
```

showing exactly the expectation and the incorrect value that was provided.

Comment: For this to work one has to include a dependency on hamcrest-library.  JUnit only depends on hamcrest-core, which does not include the Matchers class.

Comment: Tor those who don't have `Matchers` class in the Hamcrest library, you can use `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers` instead. The example from the answer is than in this form: `assertThat(i, CoreMatchers.either(CoreMatchers.is(3)).or(CoreMatchers.is(5))`

Answer (score 7):

While Harmcrest matchers can do the job, these constants can be easily refactored to a more meaninful constant, like a list of valid values. Then you can use the `contains` method to check that the value is present in the list - IMO is also easier to read:

```
public class Foo {
    public static final List<Integer> VALID_VALUES = Arrays.asList(3, 5);
}

@Test
public void testName() {
    int i = 5;
    Assert.assertTrue(Foo.VALID_VALUES.contains(i));
}
```

Comment: You would need to define a constant for each test case; I don't think this is reasonable beyond a couple of test cases. These constants will potentially be far from the place they're used. Another readability problem: `Foo.VALID_VALUES.contains(i)` is less clear than the approach with Harmcrest matchers.
Harmcrest also provides a matcher with contains, which would also be much better than this.

Comment: The Hamcrest version is a lot better because it will print the observed value on failure. There is nothing more annoying than getting a test failure back from a long CI build which just says "false was not true".

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wanted to do some complex assertion logic, so I simply implemented a method that returns a boolean and it did the job, the way it would be implemented in this example is as follows:

```
private Boolean is3or5(Integer val) {
    if(val == 3 || val == 5) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then do the assertion:

```
assertTrue(is3or5(val));
```

Of course the method can contain more complex logic if needed

Answer (score 0):

with TestNG this is also possible

```
Assert.assertTrue(val == 3 || val==5)
```