# Junit How to assert Or Condition SQL Query

Tags: junit, hamcrest

#### Or Condition Query Example

```
SELECT ID, NAME, CREATE_DATE, UPDATE_DATE 
FROM USER 
WHERE ( CREATE_DATE > SYSDATE-1 OR UPDATE_DATE > SYSDATE -1)
```

How to assert **OR Condition Query** with junit?

```
// this test is fail : createDate is "2022-07-28" || updateDate is null
String oneDaysAgo = "2022-07-27";
List<UserInfo> list = jpaRepository.findAllByCreateDateGreaterThanOrUpdateDateGreaterThan(oneDaysAgo,oneDaysAgo);
for (UserInfo vo : list) {
   assertThat(vo.getCreatedDate(), is(greaterThan(oneDaysAgo)));
   assertThat(vo.getUpdateDate(), is(greaterThan(oneDaysAgo)));
   log.info(vo.toString());
}
```

#### Expect assert

( createDate > oneDaysAgo ) or ( updateDate > oneDaysAgo )

**OneDaysAgo = "2022-07-27";**

| Create Date | Update Date | Expect Result | Actual Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null or lessThan or equal | null or lessThan or equal | False | False |
| "2022-07-28" | null or lessThan or equal | True | False |
| null or lessThan or equal | "2022-07-28" | True | False |
| "2022-07-28" | "2022-07-28" | True | True |

Comment: Maybe its enough to create test data were two entries matches and you will check if these entities are returned. Or write a test for every acceptance criteria. 3rd: Helper method that returns true if one criteria match. Edit: Even better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19064484/2683501

Comment: @pL4Gu33 thx for comment. i think can't work with http://stackoverflow.com/a/19064484/2683501
i think helper method only way to solve this problem thx !

Answer (score 0):

thx for comment @pL4Gu33

Solve problem with **Add Helper Method**

```
  @Test
  void test_orCondition() {
    String oneDaysAgo = "2022-07-27";
    List<UserVo> list = getUserVoList(oneDaysAgo);
    assertThat(list.size(), is(greaterThan(0)));
    for (UserVo vo : list) {
      assertThat(
              getOrConditionBoolean(LocalDate.parse(oneDaysAgo)
                      , vo.getCreateDate(), vo.getUpdateDate()), is(true));
    }
  }

  private Boolean getOrConditionBoolean(LocalDate baseDate, LocalDate arg1, LocalDate arg2) {
    if (checkDate(arg1, baseDate)) {
      return true;
    }
    if (checkDate(arg2, baseDate)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private boolean checkDate(LocalDate argDate, LocalDate baseDate) {
    if (argDate == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (baseDate.isEqual(argDate) || baseDate.isBefore(argDate)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Additional info/review: 
If it is a UNIT test mock the repository result and verify the repo/... is really called. If it is a INT test using a DB create a bench of testdata where you know how the filtered result look like and verify that result is coming back by that query.
The test here is not very clean